# Nonexistent structured data errors shown in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data, microformats

I am discovering Google Search Console, and I have found that my blog seems to have many errors on Google's Structured Data register (microformats.org):

[image]

When I make any live test in one of this pages, the Google Structure Data Testing Tool shows no errors and no warnings at all.

All of the pages are "Last detected" on 10/4/7

Is this because Google has an old register about my pages? They did have microdata errors on the past but are now corrected. If this would be the reason, how could I ask bots to check for this again, in order to update results?

Comment: Is it 6 October 2017? and when you corrected those errors? If structure data tool is not showing any error right now, then everything is fine, webmaster dashboard is not real time, it some times take few days based on reports type.

Comment: Those were corrected two months ago @Goyllo

Comment: Then it will disappear automatically, and don't worry it does not affect anything in ranking.